# Magento site keeps requesting login information browsing between cart & products

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

**website - http://www1.internetvoipphone.co.uk/**

Note - http://www.internetvoipphone.co.uk/ uses V1.3.2, www1 address is our V1.6 dev site before going live so please only look at that one.

**Issue** - when a user logs in then browses back to a product page they switch from https back to http which in turn logs them out, we cant find a reason why magento changes some links to https but not others

account details for testing:

username: test@test.com
password: password

I've tried resetting to the default template but the issue still occurs so it must be a magento config issue, any help greatly appreciated

Comment: The issue raises only when clicking on the logo, when clicking on home or other links is ok. True?

Comment: it logs you out any time you switch between https & http, so clicking the logo or visiting a product page are the main ones.

we've also discovered that setting use secure urls in frontend to no, clearing cache & then setting it back to yes seems to fix the issue but it only lasted around an hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be caused by cookies, we use two URL's www1.internetvoipphone.co.uk and secure.internetvoipphone.co.uk, each domain was sending out a cookie "frontend" which seem to have been conflicting.

setting the cookie domain to .internetvoipphone.co.uk generates a single cookie and as yet seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the cookie path and also the browser's cache can wreak havoc with Magento when using a development installation, even if on another domain.